# DOM traversal up to window?

Tags: javascript, dom, traversal

With the following bit of code -

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('myElement');
myEl.ownerDocument.defaultView;
```

does getting to the original window via ownerDocument.defaultView mean that I'm traversing up the DOM from the myEl element to the document and then to the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really *traversing*, per se.

Every DOM object has an `ownerDocument` property.  This is the document that the node is associated with, if any.

Every document object has a `defaultView` property (provided your browser supports it -- not true in IE <9).  This is the `window` object where the document is shown, if any,.

So it's really just reading a couple of properties from objects, rather than traversal.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say this is traversing the DOM..more like shortcutting the DOM tree and going straight to the window.

Traversal could be something more like this:

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('#myElement');
while(myEl.parentNode)
{
    console.log("parentNode = " + myEl.parentNode);
    myEl = myEl.parentNode;
}
console.log("root parentNode = " + myEl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think traversal would be like:

```
var theParentNode = document.getElementById('myElement');

while(theParentNode = theParentNode.parentNode) {
    // do something
}
```